# when button pressed...not redirecting to next page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unexpected null value.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49      throw*
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 528:63  nullCheck
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4926:44                                                                            get state
packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 2542:46                                                                            of
packages/flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart 2016:34                                                                            push
packages/facebook/main.dart 78:48                                                                                              
packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 1005:21                                                                            [_handleTap]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 198:24                                                                           invokeCallback
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 613:48                                                                                  handleTapUp
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 298:5                                                                                   [_checkUp]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 232:7                                                                                   handlePrimaryPointer
packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 563:9                                                                            handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 94:12                                                                        [_dispatch]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 139:9                                                                        
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:13          forEach
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 137:17                                                                       [_dispatchEventToRoutes]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 123:7                                                                        route
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 445:19                                                                              handleEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 425:14                                                                              dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 329:11                                                                             dispatchEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 380:7                                                                               [_handlePointerEventImmediately]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 344:5                                                                               handlePointerEvent
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 302:7                                                                               [_flushPointerEventQueue]
packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 285:32                                                                              [_handlePointerDataPacket]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1105:13               invoke1
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 185:5                 invokeOnPointerDataPacket
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 130:39                    [_onPointerData]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 543:18                    
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 496:21                    
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 210:16                    loggedHandler
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#85ae6
debugOwner: GestureDetector
state: possible
won arena
finalPosition: Offset(226.4, 466.4)
finalLocalPosition: Offset(131.4, 24.0)
button: 1
sent tap down

Comment: add the code also which is causing this issue

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow, You need to provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) So that others can test and reproduce the same error you are facing. Also  check [how-to-ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.